# Replace double quotes inside double quotes html attribute

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace, html-agility-pack

I have some cases where my clients send me a html string with some elements attributes not so correctly structured. Like this:

```
<img src="../imgTest.jpg" alt="Something "quoted here, or here"">
```

How can I **dynamically** change these cases to something like this next?

```
<img src="../imgTest.jpg" alt="Something 'quoted here, or here'">
```

*I need this html not to show on browser but to do some operations with it.*

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack to control html problems but for these cases it changes my html string to this and it isn't what I want:

```
<img src="../imgTest.jpg" alt="Something" quoted="" here,="" or="" here="">
```

**My code with HtmlAgilityPack:**

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(myHtmlStr);

var htmlError = htmlDoc.ParseErrors.SafeAny();

if (!htmlError)
    myHtmlStr = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: Well, I am afraid no regex solution for this will look nice and safe. Try [`(?<=<\w+\s[^<]*)(?<!\w+=)"(?!\s*/?>|\s+\w+=")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%3c%5cw%2b%5cs%5b%5e%3c%5d*)(%3f%3c!%5cw%2b%3d)%22(%3f!%5cs*%2f%3f%3e%7c%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%3d%22)&i=%3cimg+src%3d%22..%2fimgTest.jpg%22+alt%3d%22Something+%22quoted+here%2c+or+here%22%22%3e&r=%27) and replace with `'`.

Comment: Is your html fragment always a single element like the img in your example? Is it always the same attribute thats broken?

Comment: You can try something like [`(=\s*"[^=">]*)"([^=">]*)"([^=">]*")`](https://regex101.com/r/iK0wN9/2) and replace with `$1'$2'$3` which is not very reliable :>

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot, that works great!

Comment: @AlexK. no, isn't always a single element like img and isn't always the same attribute

Comment: @Ninita: Did it work in all cases you had? If yes, I will post with a disclaimer. Otherwise, I'll wait to see if anyone has a better idea. Mine is clear: just match a `"` if it is inside a tag and is not an attribute qualifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes in all, I tested with diferent cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to match a `"` if it is inside a tag and is not an attribute qualifier.

DISCLAIMER: This solution might not work in 100% cases (it will need adaptation in case there are namespaces added to element/attribute names), but it should work when a tag name follows the `<` immediately, double quotes are used as attribute value qualifiers, and there are no `<` symbols inside attributes.

Use

```
(?<=<\w+\b[^<]*)(?<!\w+=)"(?!\s*/?>|\s+\w+=")
```

and replace with `'`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%3c%5cw%2b%5cs%5b%5e%3c%5d%2A)(%3f%3c!%5cw%2b%3d)%22(%3f!%5cs%2A%2f%3f%3e%7c%5cs%2b%5cw%2b%3d%22)&i=%3cimg+src%3d%22..%2fimgTest.jpg%22+alt%3d%22Something+%22quoted+here%2c+or+here%22%22%3e&r=%27).

The first lookbehind ensures we are searching for a double quote indide a tag, the second one fails the match if there is a word followed with an equal sign right before the double quote, and the negative lookahead fails the match if the double quote is followed with whitespaces followed with a closing angle bracket (probably preceded with the forward slash) or when there are whitespaces followed with a word followed with an equal sign.